# Could not parse certificate from .cer to import it in keystore: Java

Tags: java, certificate, x509

I want to import exported certificate (.cer) to my application. Exports are done in PEM, DER conversion types. I have tested my exported data on online certificate decoder tools, and it shows good results, but when I want to import it in my application I've got:

> java.security.cert.CertificateException: Could not parse certificate: java.io.IOException: Empty input

Here's my source:

```
Path fileLocation = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(fileLocation);
ByteArrayInputStream bIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) 

exception -->> CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(bIn);

keystore.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);
```

**EDIT:** Method works fine with PEM format certificates, but fails to import DER.

Comment: So the file was empty.

Comment: @EJP Actually it is not, I've put breakpoint and data looked up on ByteArrayInputStream it's buf is 843 bytes length.

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that error was connected with exporting certificate in .DER type.

Here's fixed .DER export method:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath() + ".cer");
DEROutputStream dos = new DEROutputStream(fos);
ASN1InputStream asn1inputStream = new ASN1InputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(chain[0].getEncoded())); // this is Certificate
dos.writeObject(asn1inputStream.readObject());
dos.flush();
fos.flush();
dos.close();
fos.close();
```

Above import method works with both .DER and .PEM certificate formats.